Should i recode data because of a difference in directionality of scales?
I have a dataset containing roughly 2500 respondents, with 63 variables. They are mostly responses to questionnaire questions.
However, for example, one of the questions is "How often do you get bored at school?", with the answers being on a scale from 1-5, with options "Always", "Often", "Sometimes", "Rarely" and "Never" and the other question is "How often do you feel excited to go to school". The scale is the same, but in the first question, the most "desirable" answer is "never", and in the other one it is "always".
Is there going to be any incoherence when I try to, for example, correlate the data? Should I hard-recode the data via SPSS or something? Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am fairly new to statistics :>
Also, is my understanding correct, that variables such as "gender" should be nominal as there is no way to rank them, and these questions with the answer scale, should be ordinal, right? Thanks a lot!

Mathematics don't know whether "never being bored at school" is desirable or not, so the maths should be the same.

This is really a matter of taste and interpretation. It won't change any of the formal statistical results, but it could make it easier to visualize the data and interpret the results. Some judgement is needed, though — you could argue that "I always get bored at school" and "I never feel excited to go to school" should be at similar ends of the scale (i.e. both lowest or both highest), as they both represent "don't like school" answers (this might even have been the intention of whoever composed the questionnaire in the first place).
It also depends on how hard this is going to be, and whether you'll be able to use some kind of automated workflow to do the recoding without running the risk of adding errors to the data set. If you have to do it by hand it might not be worth the trouble and error-proneness.
Yes, gender should be nominal. (If "male"/"female" were the only choices then it wouldn't really matter how you coded them, since a two-level response will give the same results whether you treat it as binomial, ordinal, or nominal ...)

yeah, thats actually helpful, ill probably stick to not touching the data at a risk of screwing it up. thanks for the insight, it helped visualize it for me!

It depends on the tests you will then run on the data. E.g., if you were to use a Mann-Whitney U (or better Brunner-Munzel test), or Kruskal-Wallis on the 2 questions in your example ("How often do you get bored at school?", "How often do you feel excited to go to school?"), where one would expect similar responses, your tests will find a significant difference, just because of the reverse ordering. For other types of analysis it may not matter, but, to be safe, you should recode, so all ordinal variables are in the same "direction" (it will never hurt, but can save you in some cases). The System Usability Score (SUS) is one such scenario, where Likert questions are asked with different "directions", but the scores are coded differently.
